# How can a non-superpowered computer prodigy be a superhero?

Tags: super-powers

This character is an adolescent (~17 years old) who is basically a genius but his expertise are in computers. He has no superpowers but has decent hand-to-hand combat skills from fighting off bullies.

If he was going to be a superhero, would these skills be enough for him to fight crime?

Comment: You're asking other people to write your plot for you.  This is far too broad.  First work out a possible mechanism yourself and ask for advice on refining it (or checking it for reasonable self-consistency with your world).

Comment: Have you heard of Iron Man?

Comment: Computer geniuses are nerds that stay in front of their keyboards.  Make him the Action Hero's indispensable assistant like Alfred to Batman, or Wade to Kim Possible.

Comment: @StephenG How does this question ask anyone to write the OP's plot for him? That doesn't make sense. Also, I don't see how this can be too broad. If anything a computer prodigy with decent unarmed combat skills is ill-equipped to be a superhero. Even hitting villains over the head with a laptop doesn't cut it.

Comment: @a4android The OP should be asking something like "My hero is a computer guy who uses his skills to do X and Y.  Is this a plausible way to develop him/her as a superhero ?".  What he asked amounts to "I have no idea how to make my computer nerd a superhero using only his computer skills.  Figure that out for me.".  The first is WB territory and the closer his question was to that, the less I'd consider it too broad.  The later form is about as broad as possible and it's a major plot point without which nothing can flow.  At least that's how I see it - YMMV, of course.

Comment: The question should have been closed for another reason: Off-topic -> story instead of worldbuilding.

Comment: @StephenG Your second version is also in WB territory. Besides, whatever it is it's not a major plot point, and not even a minor one

Comment: @Renan Not really. Story-based is often bad understood. Look at the criteria of questions welcomed by WB SE in the [help center].

Comment: Related: Watch Dogs. Not related but fun: watch dogs.

Comment: He doesn't need physical prowess to be a hero, a hacker could be a hero if he uses his power right. He could build robots. There was a character in the series Heroes that could take control of electronic devices, or something like that.

Comment: @insertnoncreativeusernamehere perhaps you might read E.E. Smith's Lensman series.  The second stage Lensmen - Kimball Kinneson, Tregonsee, Worsel, and Nadrek - may have had superior physiques and almost superhuman, superrigelian, supervelantian or superpalainian fighting skills, but those were relatively minor abilities.   It was their mental powers that enabled them do more to defeat Boskone than fleets of millions of space battleships could.  Or consider how many times Sherlock Holmes had to physically fight a criminal.

Comment: My answer to this question lists a number of teenagers similar in age to your character who became  military leaders and often war heroes, despite not being super big or super strong.  If men are willing to fight under officers younger than themselves, I see no reason why crime fighters would refuse to take direction from an unseen computer user who sends them instructions and information electronically and whose age they have no clue about.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109566/how-does-an-adolescent-became-a-prominent-post-apocalyptic-leader-of-a-large-com/109652#109652

Comment: @StephenG is this edit better?

Comment: As now written your hero sounds like a good candidate for the police - make a decent cop on the beat. :-)  I think you're missing an essential point : a superhero *has* to have some ability (like an X-Man) or technology (IronMan) that exceeds what even the most gifted normal person has and they have to be able to make use of it.  You chap may be a computer genius, but that needs to be translated into something extraordinary (e.g. discovers a technique that is decades or centuries ahead of it's time and uses it to leverage crime fighting equipment beyond anything "normals" can have).

Answer (score 1):

Information is power.

Why fight hand to hand when the contents of someone's hard drive get anonymously sent to the police.

Anonymous text is sent to a future victim warning them of what will happen.

Bad guy's phone get hacked to act as a bug secretly recording all conversations.

The registration and insurance of the get away vehicle gets cancelled whilst on the way to the robbery so the police stop the vehicle.

A lot of heroes have a controller that gives them the information they need as well as protecting them from reprisals.

You don't need super powers to be a hero.

Comment: And no need for messy face-to-face fighting either. He can do it all from a comfy chair.

Comment: Wow. This gave me a better idea on how my character fights crime. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the superhero genre, there are those with clearly inhumam/supernatural powers, like **Superman** or the **Hulk**, and those with merely human powers trained to a high degree. For heroes who are supposedly normal, there comes a point where a reasonable observer would say *"OK, that's not credible for a human any more. The hero seems to have gained one PhD per month while going through SEAL training, no f...ing way."*

- Consider the endless (and pointless) debate if **Batman** could beat **Superman**. Most portrayal of Batman shy away from claiming outright superpowers, but nobody is that strong, agile, tough, and smart.
- Or compare **Agent Carter** and **Black Widow**. Agent Carter seems halfway credible as a non-super agent. She is smart, she has some combat training, but not too outrageous. Black Widow, by comparison, does some things that no normal human should be able to survive.

So there is ample precedent for a superhero without supernatural powers.

The next question is if this hero works solo or as part of a team.

- As a team member, his role would be that of *mission control*. Give him a secret base and secure communications to the *muscle* heroes on the street. At least once per episode, he will provide crucial information gathered on the net. *"Turn left, now." "But that's a dead end." "Trust me, turn left." "Coming up on a construction site." "See? No dead end."* Consider **Oracle** in the DC universe.
- As a solo superhero, he would rely on research and analysis to make force mostly unnecessary. First he finds out who the villain is, then he finds the henchpeople, then he finds out how they are vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. He fights cyber crimes.

There are a number of situations where he might be useful.
Mostly because, like him, the criminals aren't fighters exactly!

I will give you what might be an origin story for him!

He is being framed for stealing money from a bank( electronically) and in order to clear his name he goes into hiding and while searching for the real criminal he interacts with others that require his help....

Comment: if you could put some effort into describing some of those situations you could make this a proper answer

Comment: @L.Dutch I think it is enough given the question. And I knew it looks to simplistic however simplicity is very effective and it answers the question of how. Presenting situations might work to better explain what I mean and that would be unnecessary in this case! It's rather self explanatory honestly and I didn't use the comment feature because I didn't need more info!
LE: Guess I did have something more to add!